# PHP Arrays and mysqli multi query

Tags: php, arrays, mysqli, while-loop, mysqli-multi-query

I'm trying to understand two things:

1. If the following is possible;
2. What I am doing wrong with implementing it.

I have an array in PHP which is manually coded:

```
$q[1] = 'Monday';
$q[2] = 'Tuesaday';
$q[3] = 'Wednesday';
```

I have a **seperate** mysqli `multi-query` that is bringing back another set of data.  As I iterate though the multi query and echo results, I need to include information that is within the manually coded PHP array, as detailed above - my current code is as follows:

```
echo "<tr><td class='qnum'><span class='bold'>". $n .".</span></td>
<td width='450px' > ". $q[$n] ." (<span class='italics'>". $row[0] ."</span>)</td>
<td class='set2'>".$row[9]."%</td>";
```

I have a pointer `$n` that increases as the mysqli query loops through the results and I'm using the `$q[$n]` to try and pull in the relevant data from the PHP query but it doesn't work.  However, what is odd is that is I change `$q[1] = 'Monday';` to `$q = 'Monday';` and then reference `$q` in my echo statement about - it works!!!

I've also included the mysqli code for reference below:

```
if ($mysqli->multi_query($query)) {
    $n = 0;

        do {
            if ($result = $mysqli->store_result()) {
        $i = 1;
        $p = 1;

    while ($row = $result->fetch_row()) {
        $n++;

 echo "<tr><td class='qnum'><span class='bold'>". $n .".</span></td>
<td width='450px' > ". $q[$n] ." (<span class='italics'>". $row[0] ."</span>)</td>
<td class='set2'>".$row[9]."%</td>";

                echo "</tr>";
        $result->free();
    }

    } while ($mysqli->next_result());
}

$mysqli->close();
```

Any thoughts, ideas, suggestions on where I am going wrong?

Comment: if this is a proper snippet then you have a major syntax error, there is 2 loops that is not closed and also 2 if conditions that is not closed

Comment: Hi DevZer0 - it's the top half of the code - it's a huge piece of code, really to long to post here.  The loops and conditions are properly closed.

Comment: well without seeing whats going on the rest of your loop its hard to say what's wrong, can you reproduce the same problem in a reasonable set of lines to post here

Comment: I've added the bottom section of the code - that should be right.

Comment: In what way doesn't it work?

Comment: Hi Jim - when using `$q[1] = 'Monday'` and `$q[$n`] where `$n = 1` - I would expect `Monday` to be echoed - it isn't.  However, when I simply do `$q ='Monday'` and `echo $q` it works.

Comment: What happens if you `var_dump` `$q` and `$n` when in the loop?

Comment: $n comes back correctly, getting nothing for the $q.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I didn't ensure that the first PHP manual array was actually correct - rookie error!

```
$q = array(1 => 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday');
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your do-while loop is a bit odd... shouldn't the syntax be `do { ... } while(condition);`
You seem to be using a mixture of two.

Also, your `$q` has only three elements... If you're sure you want to use it with `$n` that increments in a loop, maybe use it with modulo so there's always a `$q` index for `$n`?

Example: `$q[$n % count($q)]`

I'm just fishing here because I'm not entirely sure what's your aiming at.

Comment: There are $q[1] to $q[50] - so there is no point posting all of the them!  I did three for illustrative purposes.  The manual array has 50 and also the mysqli returns 50 as well - they match.  Hence the `$q[$n]` code.